# Dynamic fields in HTML form are not responsive

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4

I am creating a dynamic form in HTML with bootstrap 4 and javascript. I want a new row of fields to be appended when I click on the "+" button. The fields are getting added but when I resize the window to check mobile responsiveness, they are not getting aligned properly. Also, I would like the "+" sign to be available at the last bottom-most row. Right now, the "+" symbol button is staying on top and the new rows are getting added below it.

I have tried adding fields with a div container around the form. Also tweaked the innerHTML code in the javascript file to change the position of the "+" sign.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>School Form</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <meta name="description" content="Welcome to the School database page.">
  <meta name="author" content="example.com">
  <!-- <link rel="icon" href="/docs/4.0/assets/img/favicons/favicon.ico"> -->
  <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
  <link href="dashboard.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
 <header>
 </header>
  <!-- Begin page content -->
   <main role="main" class="container">
    <div class="container">
     <h3>Tweets</h3><br>
      <form class="form-inline" id="education_fields">
       <div class="form-group p-2">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Schoolname" name="Schoolname[]" value="" placeholder="School name">
       </div>
       <div class="form-group p-2">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Major" name="Major[]" value="" placeholder="Major">

       </div>

       <div class="form-group p-2">

        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Degree" name="Degree[]" value="" placeholder="Degree">
       </div>
       <div class="form-group p-2">
         <select class="form-control" id="educationDate" name="educationDate[]">
          <option value="">Date</option>
          <option value="2015">2015</option>
          <option value="2016">2016</option>
          <option value="2017">2017</option>
          <option value="2018">2018</option>
         </select>
        <div class="checkbox p-1">
         <label><input type="checkbox"> Remember me</label>
        </div>
       </div>
       <button class="btn btn-success" type="button" onclick="education_fields();"><span>+</span></button>

      </form>
    </div>
    <script src="dynamicform.js"></script>
   </main>
</body>
</html>
```

The javascript file contains the following code:

```
var room = 1;

function education_fields() {
 room++;

 var objTo = document.getElementById('education_fields')

 var divtest = document.createElement("div");
 divtest.setAttribute("class", "form-group removeclass"+room);
 var rdiv = 'removeclass'+room;
 divtest.innerHTML = '<div class="form-group p-2"> <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Schoolname" name="Schoolname[]" value="" placeholder="School name"></div><div class="form-group p-2"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="Major" name="Major[]" value="" placeholder="Major"></div><div class="form-group p-2"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="Degree" name="Degree[]" value="" placeholder="Degree"></div><div class="form-group p-2"><div class="input-group"><select class="form-control" id="educationDate" name="educationDate[]"><option value="">Date</option><option value="2015">2015</option><option value="2016">2016</option><option value="2017">2017</option><option value="2018">2018</option></select><div class="checkbox p-2"><label><input type="checkbox"> Remember me</label></div><button class="btn btn-danger" type="button" onclick="remove_education_fields('+ room +');"><span>-</span></button></div></div><div class="clear"></div>';
 objTo.appendChild(divtest)

}

function remove_education_fields(rid) {
 $('.removeclass'+rid).remove();
}
```

1. I want my form fields to be mobile responsive and aligned with the subsequent rows.
2. I want the "+" sign or add button to appear beside the bottom-most row instead of the top-most.

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var room = 1;

function education_fields() {
 room++;

 var objTo = document.getElementById('inside-container')

 var divtest = document.createElement("div");
 divtest.setAttribute("class", "form-group removeclass"+room);
 var rdiv = 'removeclass'+room;
 divtest.innerHTML = '<div class="form-group p-2"> <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Schoolname" name="Schoolname[]" value="" placeholder="School name"></div><div class="form-group p-2"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="Major" name="Major[]" value="" placeholder="Major"></div><div class="form-group p-2"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="Degree" name="Degree[]" value="" placeholder="Degree"></div><div class="form-group p-2"><div class="input-group"><select class="form-control" id="educationDate" name="educationDate[]"><option value="">Date</option><option value="2015">2015</option><option value="2016">2016</option><option value="2017">2017</option><option value="2018">2018</option></select></div><div class="checkbox p-1"><label><input type="checkbox"> Remember me</label></div><button class="btn btn-danger" type="button" onclick="remove_education_fields('+ room +');"><span>-</span></button></div></div><div class="clear"></div>';
 objTo.appendChild(divtest)

}

function remove_education_fields(rid) {
 $('.removeclass'+rid).remove();
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>School Form</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <meta name="description" content="Welcome to the School database page.">
  <meta name="author" content="example.com">
  <!-- <link rel="icon" href="/docs/4.0/assets/img/favicons/favicon.ico"> -->
  <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
  <link href="dashboard.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
 <header>
 </header>
  <!-- Begin page content -->
   <main role="main" class="container">
    <div class="container">
     <h3>Tweets</h3><br>
      <form class="form-inline" id="education_fields">
       <div id="inside-container"></div>
       <div class="form-group p-2">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Schoolname" name="Schoolname[]" value="" placeholder="School name">
       </div>
       <div class="form-group p-2">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Major" name="Major[]" value="" placeholder="Major">
       </div>

       <div class="form-group p-2">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Degree" name="Degree[]" value="" placeholder="Degree">
       </div>
       <div class="form-group p-2">
         <select class="form-control" id="educationDate" name="educationDate[]">
          <option value="">Date</option>
          <option value="2015">2015</option>
          <option value="2016">2016</option>
          <option value="2017">2017</option>
          <option value="2018">2018</option>
         </select>
        <div class="checkbox p-1">
         <label><input type="checkbox"> Remember me</label>
        </div>
       </div>
       <div class="checkbox p-1">
       <button class="btn btn-success" type="button" onclick="education_fields();"><span>+</span></button>
       </div>
      </form>
    </div>
    <script src="dynamicform.js"></script>
   </main>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That worked great. Thanks for the help! Could you please help me understand the purpose of the empty div? ``` <div id="inside-container"></div> ``` Sorry for the silly question. :-)

Comment: I added empty div just above the form fields. Whenever user inserts a new row it will be added into that empty div which is just above the user input form fields which will give the new rows above the user input fields.                If you have any query feel free to ask. Thank you